# Missing Token -Metamask

Tags: tokens

I successfully bought total of 40+bn $CMF token using metamask and within couple of hrs the token start dissapearing, now Im left with less than 2 bn $CMF token. Can someone please assist me. Thanks.

Comment: Ceck your account on etherscan to see the tcs that could have cause it

Answer (score 0):

the token you bought - [CryptoMafia ($CMF)](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/cryptomafia?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6Pku_y2MmTSS9Z0ZsGd.uMpDqd5HOrxHYZmB3_UVTgw-1640272969-0-gaNycGzNCaU) - is a **rebasing** token.

*PS: just fyi, you should probably know that before buying a token(even more so when its +40bn units)*

they [mention](https://cryptomafianft.com/#token_data) it on their website:

> Rebase token that provides 2% ETH (BEP20) rewards to all holders.
> Rebase is working in this logic, reducing the supply, increasing price
> to put the chart in a upwards trend. Meaning that, your tokens may
> decrease in number after buying but the value will be kept the same!
> This operation is called “Rebasing”. Decreasing the Total Supply,
> pumping the Chart to be in Top Gainers. The only thing that you need
> to check is the actual Market Cap. As an example: – You’ve spent 100$
> and the Market Cap was 100k $. If the Market Cap goes to 200k, you are
> 2x. During this time, your tokens can decrease. It does not matter as
> the value will not change (Price Chart is irrelevant)